# Mongoose decrement one of two values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User schema with two fields:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    credits : { type: Number },
    energy: { type: Number },
});
```

What I'm trying to do is decrement one of the values depending on the other one.

If there are any credits, decrement it by 1, otherwise decrement energy by 1.

One simple solution:

```
const user = await User.findById("123");
if (user.credits > 0) {
  user.credits = model.credits - 1;
} else {
  user.energy = user.energy - 1;
}
await user.save();
```

However, I assume this is not safe for concurrency.

So I assume I would need to do something like:

```
await user.update({_id: userId}, { $inc: { energy: -1 } })
```

But is there any way to check what to decrement in an update query or another good solution?

Comment: try [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Comment: Looks like $cond is only in aggregation operation, so not update queries. So not sure if I can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found one solution, but not sure if it's the best.

```
const res = await UserModel.updateOne(
  { _id: id, coins: { $gt: 0 } }, // Matches if coins are positive
  { $inc: { coins: -1 } }, // If it's the case decrement coins
);

// If none was modified, coins must be 0,
// so we decrement energy instead
if (!res.nModified) {
  await UserModel.updateOne(
    { _id: id, energy: { $gt: 0 } }, // Make sure energy never goes negative
    { $inc: { energy: -1 } },
  );
}
```